# RSA validate p and q keys in python, python-rsa lib

Tags: python, algorithm, rsa

UPDATE

I have a program to get two public and private keys for validate those keys.

Either those key are valid or not.

We assume that our keys are valid.

```py
(pub , privateKey) = rsa.newkeys(1024)
```

However I have a relation for p, q and nlen.

This is our mathematical equation for p and q:

> 2. The primes p and q shall be selected with the following constraints:

> (a) (p–1) and (q–1) shall be relatively prime to the
> public exponent e.

> (b) The private prime factor p shall be selected and shall satisfy
> [image]

(a) condition passed successfully.

But I can't understand item (b).

In the other hands we said len(p) = len(q) = nlen/2.

`nlen` equal to size of module in bites.

Let's talk about this condition :

[image]

This codes are definitions of p, q, d, e and nlen.

```py
p = privkey.p
q = privkey.q
d = privkey.d
e = privkey.e
nlen = privkey.n.bit_length()
```

We implemented our conditions with this code :

```py
if not sqrt(2) * (2 ** ((nlen/2) - 1)) <= p <= (2 ** (nlen/2)) - 1:
     return "Invalid P prime number size"
```

And another conditions implemented with this following codes :

[image]

Check q len

```py
if not sqrt(2) * (2 ** ((nlen/2) - 1)) <= q <= (2 ** (nlen/2)) - 1:
    return "Invalid Q prime number size"
```

Above conditions didn't match and their bodies ran.

Anyway this problem is true for decryption len condition.

[image]

Second condition passes successfully.

But first throw my written error to parent class.

This my code :

```py
if not 2 ** (nlen/2) < d < lcm(p-1, q-1):
    return "Invalid decryption key"
```

But why ?

I think my problem related to nlen. cause everywhere i used nlen, my Tests didn't passed and failed.

I checked its values but i don't know what i can do for fixing this problem.

Comment: So you want a program to check if the keys provided by the rsa module are valid keys!? or do you want an algorithm to calculate key pars?

Comment: Yeah!. I wanna validate keys.

Comment: Your checks on the sizes of p and q use `sqrt(2)` which is a floating point value. This causes all the big integers to be converted to floating point approximations and this loses a great deal of precision. The result is a test that is not guaranteed to be correct. Also, nlen/2 is a floating point number. nlen//2 is an integer, but that might not be what you want unless you already know that nlen is even. In general a lot more care is needed here. But here is something to think about: why are these tests being done, and how could you use `math.isqrt()` to implement them relatively easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you text is wrong because both prime factors are only used for calculations of the keys and not published. the following answer will check if the keys are valid, not if they are secure:

In order to check if two keys are valid, you need to have the following values:

- p and q (prime numbers selected)
- n (mod-number = p * q)
- key1 and key2 (public and private key)

```py
def is_valid(p, q, key1, key2, n):  # assuming p and q are actually prime
    if n != p * q:  # check if n is actually p * q
        return False
    num = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
    if (key1 * key2) % num != 1:  # check if keys are valid
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Yeah. My keys aren't secure and this formula is just for secure keys. I switched to Cryptodome instead of rsa-python. thank you.

Comment: This is not for secure keys, this just verifies that the RSA equations will work, in other words it verifies that decryption and encryption are inverses. In particular this method returns true when key1=key2=1, and those are trivially insecure.

Answer (score 0):

This private and public keys are absolutely valid. but our conditions are true for a secure key.

We can use pycryptodome python library for increase our key tests security.

In this case we should create a key pair with those passphrases and load them with same passphrase in pycryptodome.